# Download gcm for ios without using cocoapods

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to get the Google Cloud Messaging framework without using Cocoapods? I use Carthage and don't want to have to use cocoapods just for this one library.

Comment: I think Cocoapods are the only distribution mechanism for Google APIs on iOS at this point.

Comment: Although in a bit hurry,  this may answer your question.
its containing other relevant link as well.
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm

Answer (score 0):

If you use on a demo project the pod and you put this on your PodFile

```
target 'MyTarget' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod Firebase
end
```

Then `pod install` and below Pods target you will get a .framework which you can use on your real project without using cocoapods.
It's awful to update the framework, because you need a demo project but better than nothing.

Hope it helps